# Graphql Apollo Client issue : [Network error]: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am getting a Network issue when querying graphql service from a React.js app using the apollo client.

the graphql query gets this error:

[Network error]: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.

The query :

```
<Query
  query={gql`
    query {
      items(
        param1: "value1"
        param2: "value2"
        param3: "value3"
        param4: "value4"
      ) {
        value
      }
    }
  `}
>
```

The client is as follows:
    const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://someuri/graphql",
    fetchOptions: {
      mode: "no-cors"
    }
   });

I am not sure why this is happening?

Comment: I normally see this if instead of a JSON response, the server returns HTML, for example when it hits a 404 error. What response are you seeing in the network tab?

Comment: This was due to  fetchOptions: { mode: "no-cors" } } . This had to be removed for this to work.  Thanks Daniel